# What's the way to run a PostGIS function in PyQgis

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to use PostGIS a function in a PyQgis script.

My code is:

```
qsql="(select gid, id, St_Buffer(the_geom,200) as geom from archi)"
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("ip", "port", "x", "x", "x")
uri.setDataSource("",qsql,  "the_geom","","gid")
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "test_buffer", "postgres")
if not layer.isValid:
     print 'error'
else:
     QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

The vector layer is loaded but there is NO buffer.

What's the way to run PostGIS function in PyQgis?

Comment: You need a second parameter for the buffer function that tells what buffer you want.

Comment: Yes sure,it's a mistake in code transcription, but I have used the parameter. Doesn't work

Comment: @franco_b If my answer is useful for you, please upvote it. If it solves (or helps you solve) your problem, please mark it as accepted. That's how you reward answerers in GIS.SE.

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
uri.setDataSource("",qsql,  "the_geom","","gid")
```

you are telling your script to load the geometry `the_geom`, which is your original geometry with no buffer.

You should call instead `geom`, which is the result of the buffer process, this way:

```
uri.setDataSource("", qsql, "geom", "", "gid")
```

Comment: Is there a way to create tables in order to run more than one PostGIS function in a row. (There's 10 steps in my case, subqueries would be heavy to build and not efficient)